# Uib-alert css style is not applying

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

```
<uib-alert  ng-repeat= "alert in ConfigurationAlerts"  close="closeAlert($index)">  {{alert.msg}} </uib-alert>

var eWiggle = angular.module('eWiggleApp',['ui.router', 'ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap','blockUI','ngCookies']);
```

Comment: Please elaborate your question so that viewers knows that the problem you facing while using angular bootstrap alert.

Comment: I am using ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.0.js.. trying to do uib-alert popup..Iam able to see only message .. syling is not applying. If i revert to older version it is working
older version
/*
 * angular-ui-bootstrap
 * http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

 * Version: 0.13.4 - 2015-09-03
 * License: MIT
 */

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of version 2.0 the uib-alert directive was changed to an attribute rather than an element, meaning you need to attach it to a `div`.  You haven't specified a class either, which is what determines the colour scheme of the alert.  Your example should look like this:

```
<div uib-alert ng-class="'alert-success'" ng-repeat="alert in ConfigurationAlerts"  close="closeAlert($index)"> {{alert.msg}} </div>
```

[The documentation has an example which is worth looking at.](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/alert)